# unittest received None from iterator instead of a raised error

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am still learning unittest and therefore, am unable to tell if there's a something missing in my test case in test_iterators.py below. Can someone help me to understand why the ValueError failed to be raised within unittest? Here are the scripts:

**iterators.py**

```
"""
Simple class to count from zero to N
"""
class count_to(object):
    def __init__(self, nber):
        self.nber = nber

    def __iter__(self):
        return count_to_iter(self.nber)


class count_to_iter(object):
    def __init__(self, nber):
        self.stopat = nber
        self.current_nber = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.stopat < 0:
            raise ValueError
        elif self.current_nber > self.stopat:
            raise StopIteration

        self.current_nber += 1

        return self.current_nber - 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in count_to(-1):
        print(x)
```

**tests/test_iterators.py**

```
import unittest
import iterators

class TestBaseIterators(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    # Can't get the negative test right yet. It returns None instead of raising a ValueError
    # Calling iterators.py directly and execute main successfully raised a ValueError however
    def test_negative(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError): iterators.count_to(-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have used a similar approach to test raised errors previously and it worked. However, for this particular test case, here's what I get from the test.

```
test_negative (test_iterators.TestBaseIterators) ... FAIL
NoneType: None

======================================================================
FAIL: test_negative (test_iterators.TestBaseIterators)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kerwei/Git/Concepts/tests/test_iterators.py", line 19, in test_negative
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError): iterators.count_to(-1)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I were to call iterators directly from `__main__`, I can then successfully receive the *ValueError*.

```
(py36) Kers-MacBook-Air:Concepts kerwei$ python iterators.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iterators.py", line 29, in <module>
    for x in count_to(-1):
  File "iterators.py", line 19, in __next__
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count_to(-1)` creates a new `count_to` instance, it does not iterate over it, but you placed the test on `self.stop_at` value and raise the `ValueError` in the `count_to_iter.__next__` method, so you will obviously not get a ValueError until you iterate on the `count_to` instance.

The naive fix would be to force iteration, ie:

```
def test_negative(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError): 
        # passing the iterable to `list` will force iteration
        list(iterators.count_to(-1))
```

But the root problem is actually more of a design issue: raising a ValueError at this point is far from optimal since it will only happen when actually consuming the iterable, so you will have to inspect the call stack up until you find where `count_to` has been passed a wrong value. A much better solution is to check the value and eventually raise directly at the point where `count_to` is instanciated so it breaks always and immediatly (instead of "eventually, when you try to use the iterator in some possibly remote part of the code):

```
class count_to(object):
    def __init__(self, nber):
        if nber < 0:
            raise ValueError("count_to argument must be a positive integer")
        self.nber = nber

    def __iter__(self):
        return count_to_iter(self.nber)
```

And then your current test code will work as intended.

Comment: Thanks, this is spot on! I totally overlooked the part where I instantiated the iterator but did not do anything with it. Also appreciate your insights on the design flaw. The point about tracing the stack upwards really make my original construct looks really hideous :P